# LARAVEL 5.3 - Mark field by name after server side validation

Tags: javascript, laravel, validation, laravel-blade, server-side-validation

So my question is how to mark/show messages via javascript after server-side validation. I know there's the `$errors` inside blade views but there's no way of telling which element could not be validated. The only way of knowing is to do `$errors->first(...)` but then you get stuck with only this frustrating option:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'title=' . $errors->first('password') : '' }} placeholder="Password" name="password" required="required">
</div>
```

While it's acceptable to do that, I'm aiming at reusability, something that can be easily implemented and troubleshot later on other pages.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) form package?

> This allows you to quickly build forms that not only bind to model
>   values, but easily re-populate if there is a validation error on the
>   server!

It make easier to create forms, retrieve old values and display errors. It also make the code cleaner. For example:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}

    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'awesome']) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Check the [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html).